Buenas, tengo dos problemas con mi menu para adaptarlo a dispositivo movil
Mi primer problema con el menu es que al darle click al icono del menu hamburguesa se despliega el menu bien, luego le doy click al submenu y se despliega el otro submenu en caso de tenerlo pero el primer click hace que se abra y se cierra recien a partir del segundo click lo hace bien, no he podido arreglarlo.
El segundo problema es que no me cierra los otros submenus, cuando los voy abriendo quedan abiertos  ademas del que esta activo, al igual que cuando doy click fuera y se cierra el menu principal cuando lo vuelvo a abrir queda en donde estaba abierto el submenu o lo que fuese que haya visto.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const menuToggle = document.getElementById('menu');
        const navUl = document.getElementById('nav-ul');
    
        menuToggle.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            navUl.classList.toggle('show');
        });
    
        document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            if (navUl.classList.contains('show') && 
      !navUl.contains(event.target) && event.target !== menuToggle) {
                navUl.classList.remove('show');
              }
         });
      });
    
      $(".submenu").click(function(){
         $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
     })
    
     $("ul").click(function(p){
        p.stopPropagation();
     })
/*-------------Menu Hamburguesa-------------------*/
        
        #menu {
            display: block;
            margin-left: 325px;
        }
        
        
        /*-------------->Menu<-----------------*/
        
        
        .container {
            height: 55px;
        }
        
        .container nav #nav-ul {
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            height: 246px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            top: 55px;
            left: 0;
            transform: translateX(-100%);
            transition: all 0.6s;
            background-color: rgb(40, 44, 44);
        }
        
        .container nav #nav-ul ul {
            position: static;
        }
        
        .container nav #nav-ul li {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            border: solid 1px black;
        }
        
        .container nav ul li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 15px; 
            margin: auto;
            text-align: left;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        #carrito a span {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            right: 5px;
            top: 15px;
        }
        
        #carrito ul.show {
           transform: translateX(0%);
        }
        
        
        .container nav ul li ul {
            width:100%;
        }
        
        .container nav ul li ul li a{
            width: 100%;
            background-color: rgb(76, 44, 120);
            color: green;
        }
        
        .container nav ul li ul li ul li a{
            background-color: rgb(158, 99, 218);
            color: #eeff00;
        }
        
        .container nav ul li ul li ul li ul li a{
            background-color: rgb(179, 129, 230);
            color: aqua;
        }
        
        .container nav ul li a:hover {
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);   
        }
        
        .container nav ul li ul a:hover {
            background-color: rgb(19, 3, 3);
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <span id="menu"><span class="ico icomenu"></span></span>
                <nav id="carrito">
                    <ul id="nav-ul">
                        <li><a href="#"></a>Menu</li>
                        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Menu</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"></a>Submenu</li>
                                <li><a href="#"></a>Submenu</li>
                                <li><a href="#"></a>Submenu</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a>Menu</li>
                        <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Menu</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="submenu"><a href="#">Submenu</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a>Menu</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
    </html>



